# How to make a neural network of nodes with equal weights in Keras, preferably functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to make a model like the below picture. (simplified)

[image: here's a link to my neural nets schema picture]

So, practically, I want the weights with the same names to always have the same values during training. What I did was the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

example_train_features = np.arange(12000).reshape(1000, 12)
example_lanbels = np.random.randint(2, size=1000)    #these data are just for illustration purposes
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((example_train_features, example_lanbels)).shuffle(buffer_size = 1000).batch(32)

dense1 = layers.Dense(1, activation="relu")     #input shape:4
dense2 = layers.Dense(2, activation="relu")     #input shape:1
dense3 = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")  #input shape:6
feature_input = keras.Input(shape=(12,), name="features")
nodes_list = []
for i in range(3):
    first_lvl_input = feature_input[i :: 4]      ######## marked line
    out1 = dense1(first_lvl_input)
    out2 = dense2(out1)
    nodes_list.append(out2)

joined = layers.concatenate(nodes_list)
final_output = dense3(joined)
model = keras.Model(inputs = feature_input, outputs = final_output, name="extrema_model")
compile_and_fit(model, train_ds, val_ds, patience=4)
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              metrics=keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy())
history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10, validation_data=val_ds)
```

But when I try to run this code I get this error:

```
MklConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0][0]= 71 vs. shape[18][0] = 70
     [[node extrema_model/concatenate_2/concat (defined at <ipython-input-373-5efb41d312df>:398) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_15338]
```

(please don't pay attention to numbers as they are from my real code) this is because it gets the whole data including the labels as an input, but shouldn't Keras only feed the features itself? Anyway, if I write the marked line as below:

```
    first_lvl_input = feature_input[i :12: 4]
```

it doesn't give me the above error anymore. But, then I get another error which I know why happens but I don't know how to resolve it.

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [4,1] vs. [32,1]
     [[node gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs 
(defined at <ipython-input-1-b82546367b3c>:398) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6098]
```

This is because keras is feeding again the whole batch array, whereas in Keras documentation it is written you shouldn't specify the batch dimension for the program as it understands itself, so I expected Keras to feed the data one by one for my code to work. So I appreciate any ideas on how to resolve this or on how to write a code for what I want. Thanks.

Comment: The model in the picture is NOT a fully connected network, but your functional model is fully connected.

Comment: I understand, the first hidden layer has just one unit, not three. so the net is fully connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the dense layers in timedistributed wrapper , and reshape your data to have three dimensions (1000,3,4)(batch, sequence, feature), so for each time step (=3 that replace your for loop code .) the four features will be multiplied with the same weights each time.

```
example_train_features = np.arange(12000).reshape(1000, 3, 4 )
example_lanbels = np.random.randint(2, size=1000)    #these data are just for illustration purposes
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((example_train_features, example_lanbels)).shuffle(buffer_size = 1000).batch(32)

dense1 = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(1, activation="relu"))     #input shape:4
dense2 =layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(2, activation="relu"))     #input shape:1
dense3 = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")   #input shape:6
feature_input = keras.Input(shape=(3,4), name="features")


out1 = dense1(feature_input)
out2 = dense2(out1)
z = layers.Flatten()(out2)

final_output = dense3(z)

model = keras.Model(inputs = feature_input, outputs = final_output, name="extrema_model")

model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              metrics=keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy())
history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10)
```